# Access extensions from parent folder

Tags: r, directory, quarto

I have a quarto website with the following file structure where the `slides.qmd` are rendered individually. I was wondering if I can reference in the revealjs-yml of `slides.qmd` the `_extensions` folder of the parent folder? What works, but I try to avoid, is to copy the extensions folder manually to the `01-content` folder.

```
    ├── _extensions
    │   ├── quarto-ext
    │   │   └── fontawesome
    ├── content
    │   └── index.qmd
    │   ├── 01-content
    │   │   ├── slides.qmd
    ├── _quarto.yml
```

I thought about something like this might work:

````
---
title: "slide example"
format:
  revealjs: 
    filters:
      - "../../_extensions/quarto-ext/fontawesome"
---

## Hello World

```{r}
#| echo: true
print(123)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, its not possible to include such relative path for extensions in `filter`. Instead, use that extension in the project specific `_quarto.yml` file which will affect the qmd files in the children directories.

So for the following directory structure,

```bash
.
|----- _quarto.yml
|----- _extensions
| |--- quarto-ext
| | |____fontawesome
| | | |---- _extension.yml
| | | |---- fontawesome.lua
|---- contents
| |---- slides
| | |---- test.qmd
```

**_quarto.yml**

```yaml
filters: 
  - fontawesome
```

rendering the following works as intended.

```
---
title: "slide example"
format: revealjs
---

## Hello World

{{< fa thumbs-up >}} 
{{< fa folder >}}
```

---

[image: fa icons on revealjs slide]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer - that it is not possible atm more or less answers my question, but your solution does not work for me unfortunately due to my specific structure where the slides.qmd is rendered in its own working directory and not the parent one.

Comment: I have actually rendered the `slide.qmd`  in its own directory using quarto cli command `quarto render slides.qmd` and it worked. So I am curious and confused why it did not worked for your case.

Comment: It has to do with a bit complicated targets pipeline structure (a bit difficult to explain), but thank you very much for your effort! :)